# using ansi escape codes to change the background color in xfce4-terminal

Tags: colors, escape-characters, xfce4-terminal

This works to change the background color for the entire terminal with xterm:

```
printf '\033]10;%s\a\033]11;%s\a' Blue Red
```

It doesn't work in xfce4-terminal, tho.  Is there something that will work?  Note, I want a command line solution.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with the current version of xfce-terminal (4.12), since it uses an ancient, Gtk+2-based vte for terminal emulation. You should wait until they port their code to the new, Gtk+3-based vte, or switch to another terminal emulator (e.g. gnome-terminal).

Comment: To whoever downvoted my post: By the time I posted it, it was a perfectly valid answer. By now (when you downvoted it, Aug '19) it's indeed obsolete. It would have been much more appropritate to file a comment about it than downvoting. Next time please check the date of the answer before taking action.